# How to apply the schedule for the themes?

Tags: magento2

I'm new for magento 2.

Anyone let me know how can I apply the schedule for the different themes.

Comment: Please, explain more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this, http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-apply-the-schedule-for-theme/

1) Login to Admin panel

2) Go to Content > Design > Schedule

3) Click on “Add new Design” theme

4) Select the theme,start date, from date and save the design theme